# String pattern searching in Multidimensional String array [,]

Tags: c#, arrays, string, c#-4.0, multidimensional-array

Let's Assume I have Multi dimensional Object array that represents employee information for example

```
String[,] Employee= new object[,] { 
             {"john","MBA#MBA#BE#MBA#BE"},
             {"jan","MS#MSC#MBA"},

};
```

Visualize

```
 john                 MBA#MBA#BE#MBA#BE    
 jan                   MS#MSC#MBA
```

I want remove the duplicated data ( where data is divided by #)

```
 john                 MBA#BE   
 jan                  MS#MSC#MBA
```

Comment: Why don't you create a proper class instead of using arrays?

Comment: You'd better use a dictionary for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this scenario it's better to use a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, string> employee = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"john", "MBA#MBA#BE#MBA#BE"},
    {"jan", "MS#MSC#MBA"}
}

Dictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (var kvp in employee)
{
    result[kvp.Key] = string.Join("#", kvp.Value.Split('#').Distinct());
}
```

The `result` dictionary will contain the result:

```
// Prints "MS#MSC#MBA"
Console.WriteLine(result["jan"]);

// Prints "MBA#BE"
Console.WriteLine(result["john"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd create a class to hold that information

```
public class Employee
{
    public Employee(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Degress = new HashSet<string>();
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public HashSet<string> Degrees { get; private set; }
}
```

Then you can populate a list of them like this

```
string[,] employeeArray = { { "john", "MBA#MBA#BE#MBA#BE" }, { "jan", "MS#MSC#MBA" } };

List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

for (int i = 0; i < employeeArray.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    Employee employee = new Employee(employeeArray[i,0]);
    foreach (var degree in employeeArray[i, 1].Split('#'))
    {
        employee.Degrees.Add(degree);
    }

    employees.Add(employee);
}

foreach (var e in employees)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Name + " " + string.Join(" ", e.Degress));
}
```

Which prints

> john MBA BE
>
> jan MS MSC MBA

Because `Degrees` is a `HashSet` it will not allow duplicates, and when you attempt to pass a duplicate to `Add` it will just return `false`.